# Can't create constructor overloading in entity class of Room Database

Tags: android, android-room

I'm getting runtime error if I overload a constructor in entity class of room database. I'm not getting any resource by by searching in google regarding this issue. However, In developer site they have mentioned

> Note: Entities can have either an empty constructor (if the corresponding DAO class can access each persisted field) or a constructor whose parameters contain types and names that match those of the fields in the entity. Room can also use full or partial constructors, such as a constructor that receives only some of the fields.

While creating `public Category(String name){this.name = name;}` I'm getting a runtime error. My code of Category class is in the following

```
@Entity
public class Category {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public int type;

    public Category(String name, int type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Category(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
       return name;
    }

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably it is talking about only one constructor.  What is the error it is showing?

Answer (score 1):

Room can only work with Constructors without arguments. If you need another constructor, annotate it with `@Ignore`